# What performance hit does using "rows.render()" have in web2py?

Tags: web2py, data-access-layer

I have found that using the 'Represents' functionality as described in http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer?search=lazy#Rendering-rows-using-represent slows things down quite a lot - more than doubles the time it takes to process some tables. This is a shame because this option makes it really easy to get human readable data from very simple table SELECTs.

I think this performance is to be expected since I assume it is issuing a SELECT for every record to get the Represents values. So I have 1 SELECT for my set of, say, 100 records and then there is another 100+ SELECTS to get the Represent values for the fields in one or more related tables as I access those records.

Any tips on how to improve the render() function performance?
Or should I expect the render() option to be sluggish?
Is the only alternative to build a query with the necessary joins in order to get the Represents data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `reference` fields that refer to a related table with a `format` attribute defined will get a `represent` function that does indeed select the related record (and then applies the `format` function/specification to the retrieved record), leading to the "N+1" query problem you have observed.

If you still want to make use of `rows.render()` to apply the `represent` functions of other types of fields that do not involve database selects, you can eliminate the problem for `reference` fields by explicitly removing their default `represent`  attributes:

```
Field('other_table', 'reference other_table', represent=None)
```

Of course, in that case, you do not get the nicely formatted presentation of the `other_table` field. As you suggest, the more efficient alternative in that case is to build a query that joins the related table.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. There are some tables where I don't show the reference fields so I could remove some of them. I might see if that helps.

Comment: You could also simply exclude the reference fields from the query altogether, in which case calling `rows.render()` will not do anything with the reference fields.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My query is rudimentary at the moment so it includes all fields. I can  tweak that.